# Responsive slides and footer positioning

Tags: html, css

Okay so my footer was working fine until I've installed responsiveslides. It was at the bottom of the page, position:absolute, not fixed, but now it stays in the middle of the page and under it there is blank space.
I know that position:absolute makes it stay just under the last anchored element, but I don't understand why it doesn't stand after the divs and it sticks just under the slideshow.

**Code Snippet Demonstration :**

```css
.slideshow-container {
    clear: both;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 80;
}

.rslides {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.rslides li {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        position: relative;
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            float: left;
}

.rslides img {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        border: 0;
}

#continut {
    height: 1000px;
}

#footer {
    clear:both;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #F28A00;
}

#footer ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1.041vw;     
}

#footer li { 
        font-size: 0.9vw;
        font-weight:normal;
        display: inline;
        margin-left: 2.604vw;
        padding-right: 0.78125vw;
        padding-bottom: 0.263vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

            <ul class="rslides">
                <li><img src="img/img1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="img/img2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="img/img3.jpg" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
            <script src="js/sshow.js"></script>
        </div>
            <div id="continut"></div>
            <div id="continut2"></div>
            <div id="continut3"></div>
            <footer id="footer">
                <ul>
                    <li id="nume">x</li>
                    <li class="copyright">Copyright Ⓒ 2017</li>
                </ul>
            </footer>     
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove `bottom:0` in the #footer [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Karthik6699/qhfthpn9/) .Everything works fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Change `absolute` into `inherit` in `#footer` and you might want to delete `bottom: 0;`

```css
.slideshow-container {
    clear: both;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 80;
}

.rslides {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.rslides li {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        position: relative;
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            float: left;
}

.rslides img {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        border: 0;
}

#continut {
    height: 1000px;
}

#footer {
    clear:both;
    position: inherit;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #F28A00;
}

#footer ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1.041vw;     
}

#footer li { 
        font-size: 0.9vw;
        font-weight:normal;
        display: inline;
        margin-left: 2.604vw;
        padding-right: 0.78125vw;
        padding-bottom: 0.263vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

            <ul class="rslides">
                <li><img src="img/img1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="img/img2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="img/img3.jpg" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
            <script src="js/sshow.js"></script>
        </div>
            <div id="continut"></div>
            <div id="continut2"></div>
            <div id="continut3"></div>
            <footer id="footer">
                <ul>
                    <li id="nume">x</li>
                    <li class="copyright">Copyright Ⓒ 2017</li>
                </ul>
            </footer>     
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way : set this : `body{position: relative;}` . 
second way :
you can wrap your footer in another element with position:relative :

```css
.slideshow-container {
    clear: both;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 80;
}

.rslides {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.rslides li {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        position: relative;
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            float: left;
}

.rslides img {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        border: 0;
}

#continut {
    height: 1000px;
}

#footer {
    clear:both;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #F28A00;
}

#footer ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1.041vw;     
}

#footer li { 
        font-size: 0.9vw;
        font-weight:normal;
        display: inline;
        margin-left: 2.604vw;
        padding-right: 0.78125vw;
        padding-bottom: 0.263vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

            <ul class="rslides">
                <li><img src="img/img1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="img/img2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="img/img3.jpg" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
            <script src="js/sshow.js"></script>
        </div>
            <div id="continut"></div>
            <div id="continut2"></div>
            <div id="continut3"></div>
            <div style='position:relative'><footer id="footer">
                <ul>
                    <li id="nume">x</li>
                    <li class="copyright">Copyright Ⓒ 2017</li>
                </ul>
            </footer>    
            </div>
            </div>
```